# How to detect page redirect with PHP?

Tags: php, image, file, detect, exists

I'm trying to detect whether an image exists on a remote server. However, I've tried several methods and can't get any of them to work.

Right now I'm trying to use this:

```
if (!CheckImageExists("http://img2.netcarshow.com/ABT-Audi_R8_2008_1024x768_wallpaper_01.jpg")) {
    print_r("DOES NOT EXIST");
} else {
    print_r("DOES EXIST");
};

function CheckImageExists($imgUrl) {
    if (fopen($imgUrl, "r")) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};
```

But it returns 'true' whether the image actually exists or not (the above image should, but change it to gibberish and it still will return 'true'). I have a feeling it could be because if the URL does not exist, it redirects to the homepage of the site. But I don't know how to detect that.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can easily test that hypothesis by pasting the URL into a browser (unless you are thinking that PHP is redirecting...but I can tell you it's not)

Comment: Oh I know for sure that it's redirecting- if the image doesn't exist, it just redirects to the homepage of the site. That URL I'm testing above is valid, you can try it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

After fetching the resource, you can get the error code calling [curl_errno()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php).

Comment: I've tried that method as well, however, I get back a code '200' whether the image actually exists or if it doesn't and just redirects. So I don't know how I can use that to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Code 200 is for OK, which means it's not a 404 so forget about that. I see that if I request http://img2.netcarshow.com/ABT-Audi_R8_2008_1024x768_wallpaper_01.jpg2, which doesn't exist, I get a valid page. Given this site is not W3C compliant (does not send 404), you'll need to handle this one manually - i.e. inspect the received content to see if it's an 'custom' 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

The chances are you are getting a HTML page back into your $imgUrl that contains "404 image not found" or something similar.

You should be able to check the response for a code indicating that the request failed or redirected.

Comment: How would I go about checking the code? Because as I said above, one method I tried would return code '200' whether the image actually existed, or didn't exist and just redirected.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (using image size):

```
if (!CheckImageExists("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png")) {
    echo 'DOES NOT EXIST';
} else {
    echo 'DOES EXIST';
};

function CheckImageExists($imgUrl) {
    if (@GetImageSize($imgUrl)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};
```

Comment: I've tried that method as well, but it always returns 'false', even for images that do exist.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with Seb's method. Just used YQL to inspect the actual content of the page and determine if it's an error or not.